# While loop and match records in one foreach with another

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the code that I will be using:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'office',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
]);

$offices = [];
if (count($wp_query->posts) > 0) {
    $offices = $wp_query->posts;
}

$settings['started'] = time();

foreach ($offices as $office) {
    $key['_office_id'] = get_post_meta($office->ID, '_office_id', true);
}

foreach ($records as $record) {
    $record_key = strtoupper(str_replace(' ', '',
        trim($record->location_id) . trim($record->business_unit)));
}
```

$key outputs the following:

```
Array
(
    [_office_id] => ATLANTAFHUSA
)
Array
(
    [_office_id] => AUSTINFHUSA
)
```

$record_key outputs the following:

```
ATLANTAFHUSA
AUSTINFHUSA
```

Here is what I'm trying to achieve .. I want to create a while loop inside the records foreach that will look at the $record_key and if there is a match with $key['_office_id'] to go ahead and echo that out.

What I attempted inside the $records foreach:

```
while ($record_key == $key['_office_id']) {
    if ($record_key == $key['_office_id']) {
        echo $record_key . " has a matching record.";
    } else {
        echo $record_key . " does not have a matching record.";
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you build arrays in loops/if blocks - it's always (IMHO) good practice to define the variable beforehand.  So `$key = [];` before your code `foreach ($offices as $office) {`

Comment: Use `$key = array()` before `foreach` loop

Comment: `$key['_office_id']` is overwritten on every iteration of first `foreach`, are you sure it is correct behaviour?

Comment: I could always improve it, thanks for all the help guys! I'm changing my key variable now @u_mulder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$keys = [];
// Store all office ids
foreach ($offices as $office) {
    $keys[] = get_post_meta($office->ID, '_office_id', true);
}

foreach ($records as $record) {
    $record_key = strtoupper(str_replace(' ', '',
        trim($record->location_id) . trim($record->business_unit)));

    // Check if current `record_key` is in `$keys` array
    if (in_array($record_key, $keys)) {
        echo 'Record key is in keys';
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this cause it to loop through each $keys (let's say 100+ times), till it finds all the $record_keys? Trying to loop through the offices one time, and build an array.

Comment: I doubt that you notice that your script is slow. But if you need to speed up you can use `isset` with `$keys` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will look into that now.